# How do you find character after a specific character in file

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a `.txt` file which a sample would be like this:

```
Item 1        $1.00
Item #        $2.00
Item &        $3.50
Item (        $0.30
```

If I want to ask the user to input the item they want and find the price, how can I do that?

I have tried using `.find()` to solve the problem, but it didn't work because array cannot use `.find()`.

I'm new to C++, please explain.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
string product;
ifstream file("Item.txt");

int main(){
    cout << "Enter item you want" << endl;
    cin >> product;
    file.open("Item.txt", fstream::ate);
    findItem.find((file.begin(),file.end(), product) + 1);
    cout << findItem << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `product`? Where does that come from? What is `inventory`? This is a hint of the code you have, it is not something we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have edited the code, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: `main int(){` -- Does your C++ book show declaring the `main` function this way?

Comment: Why do you include `item.txt`? You can include only header and source files.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a "Beginners' Guide" to any programming language. There is clearly a lot you need to learn about C++ programming but this isn't the place to do so.

Comment: Where's the definition of `findItem`?

Comment: Your data file would be easier to parse if you used commas to separate the fields.

Comment: Why are you using `fstream::ate`? What is `findItem` and how is it populated? Also, your item names have spaces in them, but `operator>>` doesn't read spaces. To read input with spaces, use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: Rather than search a file (though there are use cases for this, I suspect for a beginner this is not the best way to learn). I would define a class to represent each item. Load each item from the file into a vector. Then you can search the vector for the item you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code fragment to search your file:

```
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(file, text_line))
{
    std::string text_item;
    std::string item_name;
    char        dollar_sign;
    double      price;
    std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
    text_stream >> text_item >> item_name >> dollar_sign >> price;
    if (product == item_name)
    {
        std::cout << "Found item\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

The usual method is to create a class that models the input line, then overload `operator>>` to read from a stream.

*Notes: 1) commas separating fields would make reading easier; 2) Remove the dollar sign to make reading easier.*